# use xdebug function trace in browser with large php projects

Tags: php, function, call, xdebug, trace

I'm working on a complex PHP project (vanillaforum open source with 1000 files, based on an MVC framework).  Am trying to understand what code (list of function calls and files) is executed when i request a simple URL like /localhost/index.php

I used xDebug function trace that is getting output to a log file - it generates a 24MB file, which doesn't make it any easier to understand the code.  Note that adding xdebig trace commands in the php code is not a solution, because i don't know where to insert code.  How can I

1) Is there a setting that will limit the output to significant calls so i can actually follow the sequence?   or hints/keywords i can search in the output?

2) I tried ?XDEBUG_SESSION_START as a URL parameter, but didn't see any trace output in the browser or the file output - how can i get the output in the browser easily, so i don't have to open the trace file every time?

3) Is there some interactive/WYSIWYG tool that simplifies function call tracing - i've looked at Eclipse PDT, PHP Designer, Aptana and they all have good Debuggers (which are useful only after you know your code well).

thanks
Kiran